# Identify this waterfall in Myanmar

Tags: identify-this, myanmar, waterfalls

Planning my next trip to Myanmar I've found this image in [this website](http://www.wanderlusttravel.com.mm/tour-programs/yangon-putao-machanbaw-myitkyina-myitsone-indawgyi-lake/).

[image]

According to the site this should belong to one of these places: Yangon, Putao, Machanbaw, Myitkyina, Myitsone or Indawgyi Lake, but I can't find where. Google reverse image search points to Vietnam... Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the [Ban Gioc–Detian Falls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ban_Gioc%E2%80%93Detian_Falls) on the [border of China and Vietnam](https://www.google.com/maps?ll=22.8564,106.722&q=22.8564,106.722&hl=en&t=m&z=15). Here's a picture from another angle from Wikipedia:

[image]

Comment: Vietnam? So the website has taken a random picture from Internet...

Comment: Oh come on FGITW! Add some details. :P

Comment: @Ivan people have been known to lie on the Internet...

Comment: Are you sure? I can't see anything that could be the second tier in the pic in the question, and I can't see anywhere the wooden building or left-side mountains from the pic in the question could be in the pic in your answer. If either image is reversed the beaches don't seem to match up

Comment: @user568458 I'm 100% sure this is the right place. Compare to other pics on the web.

Comment: +1 You're right, with a slight proviso - there are two neighbouring waterfalls, your pic shows the main falls, the pic in the question shows the smaller neighbour - you can see both in this image which also shows the wooden building http://img.hanoitv.vn/zoom/460/Uploaded/HoangManh/2013_07_20/Thac%20Ban%20Gioc3.jpg your image matches the right, the question matches the left